# How Hadoop Map and Reduce frameworks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a 1GB file. It is a simple text file. I have a 3 node cluster. If I write a Java MapReduce program to count for each word its occurrence, how may times a Mappers Map() will be called and Reducers reduce method be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the size of the cluster is not important. It will result in some redundant calls, just for fault tolerance, but I guess this is not your question. So, if you have a 1-node cluster or a 100-node cluster, the number of map and reduce tasks will be the same and the result will be the same.

Now, for the number of map tasks, this depends on a few things, such as the size of a block and the format of the input. You can find details about the number of mappers in [this article](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces).

Now for the number of times that the reduce method will be called, this is much easier to define. In a wordcount program, the output key of the mappers is a word. So, each distinct word will end up in a different invocation to the reduce method. In other words, the number of times a reduce method is called, is equal to the number of distinct words that exist in your dataset.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. the above answer fits the answer